# Summing up in html using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Why can't i sum the revenue this code just displays the last revenue in TOTAL: how to properly sum?

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
       <th>Date</th>
      <th>Route</th>
      <th>Destination</th>
      <th>Van No.</th>
      <th>Waybill No.</th>
      <th>Charge Invoice</th>
      <th>Revenue</th>
      <th>Strip/Stuff</th>


    </tr>

  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>

      <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_date']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_route']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_destination']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_van_no']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_waybill_no']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_charge_invoice']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_revenue']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_strip_stuff']; ?></td>

     <?php $revenue = $row_PK['delivery_details_revenue'];
      $sum += $revenue;?>

        </tr>  
          <?php } while ($row_PK = mysql_fetch_assoc($PK));?>





      </table>

TOTAL: <?php echo $revenue; ?> <br/>
```

TOTAL just shows the last recorded revenue it does not add all of them why?

Comment: You're not outputting the sum obviously. Is `$sum += $revenue;` your code? Do you know what it does? Then look at the last `echo` again.

Comment: You can't loop through a resultset with a `do...while` loop unless your `$row_PK` variable is set before the loop, which it does not appear to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first glace one error i notice is that you echo your $revenue variable at the end which is just the last loaded data... try echoing $sum and if that is some unexpected result we can look at the structure of for loop. But that variable swap may be the only issue.

Also for the structure of your while loop I feel like it is safer to put your conditional on the top... this may work but whenever I look at a while loop the conditional is at the top so it is good to try and follow common convention. e.g.

```
<?php
while ($row_PK = mysql_fetch_assoc($PK)) {
?>
//your code
<?php
 $revenue = $row_PK['delivery_details_revenue'];
      $sum += $revenue;
}
echo $sum;
?>
```

Comment: nice, you are correct how stupid of me thanks for pointing out my error

Comment: @JustinCapunoCuizon: It's alright we all make those small errors from time to time. Also please make sure to check off my solution as the answer so others users know your problem was resolved. Have a nice day.

Comment: i checked it but it said wait for 5 mins xD

Comment: @JustinCapunoCuizon: That is interesting, but I guess it is good that StackOverflow has that built-in security measure to ensure everyone gets the chance to answer. Even though it can lead to these situations where the solution was just a small typo.